# Очистка строки

Tags: android, java

Дана строка, содержащая цифры и спец. символы, допустим, `%$@()#+`; нужно очистить эту строку и оставить в ней только цифры от 0 до 9, те если была строка 773221(+22, то должна получиться 77322122. Как реализовать такое?

Comment: Регулярные выражения, видимо

Comment: Видимо, только я вот с ними не работал совершенно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   public String filterString ( final String data, final String filter )
   {
      char ch;
      final StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer ();
      for ( int i = 0; i < data.length (); i++ )
      {
         ch = data.charAt ( i );
         if ( -1 == filter.indexOf ( ch ) )
         {
            res.append ( ch );
         }
      }

      return res.toString ();
   }
```

Comment: StringBuffer здесь ни к чему. Надо использовать StringBuilder. Можно также указать заранее размер для буфера (в худшем случае его размер будет составлять исходную строку). И final очень уж понатыкали. И data.length надо законстантить, чтобы не делать на каждой итерации цикла. Но в целом приемлемое решение.

Comment: Вы всегда сохраняете длину строки в отдельной переменной? А вот мне казалось, что современные компиляторы инлайнят в этой ситуации, а если еще учесть, что length() (как и size() у ArrayList, например) возвращают лишь this.length (this.size), то разницы не будет.

Comment: это решение подходит только в том случае если у вас небольшое количество символов которые нужно удалить, в противном случае лучше сделать с RegExp как предложил  @a_gura

p.s. да, вы правы, можно убрать final, добавить начальный размер для SB, и если Вы посмотрите в исходный код то увидите что length() возвращает константу. но думаю выиграш(или проиграш) нескольких наносекунд в данной ситуации не принципиально.

Comment: стоит добавить, что здесь уже есть [похожее решение][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/4989/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-java/14543

Comment: Про длину.. я провёл измерения: выигрыш от введения переменной составляет ~8% (в моём тесте 12 секунд против 13). С увеличением количества итераций время выполнения снижается в обоих вариантах, но пропорция сохраняется (113,5s против 126,6 - десять секунд это совсем не мало). С другой стороны, если речь идёт о пяти символах и выполняется раз в месяц, то это действительно ерунда.

Answer (score 5):

Варианта два:

- Использовать метод replaceAll класса String. Если нужно оставить только цифры, например так:

  [str.replaceAll("\\D+", "");](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

В целях оптимизации имеет смысл явно использовать возможности пакета java.util.regex и прекомпилированное регулярное выражение.

- Перебрать все символы строки и оставить только те, что являются цифрой (см. метод [isDigit класса Character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)))

Answer (score 1):

**s** - строка, которую необходимо обработать

**slength** - длина обрабатываемой строки

**res** - результат

```
for (int j = 0; j < slength; j++)
     if (s[j] >= '0' && s[j] <= '9') 
          res += s[j];
```

Comment: Это плохая идея. Если уж на то пошло, используйте уж StringBuilder и сравнение отвратительное, хотя и эффективное.

Comment: @cy6erGnom

вопрос стоял об эффективном алгоритме? я написал ответ, как ВОЗМОЖНОЕ решение проблемы! Я видел много ответов, которые были недостаточно хорошими, но всё же решали проблему, и мне что, на них всех минус уважение ставить? Не проще ли Вам предложить своё мегаэффективное решение?

жаль, что нет возможности оценить Ваш комментарий на мой ответ (не в лучшую сторону)...

Comment: ну а зачем создавать ответы, не имеющие под собой никакого смысла? кто будет реально использовать подобный код, скажите мне?) зачем плодить безграмотность?
уф.. вот :)

Comment: А по моему просто и понятно.

Comment: @Tim Rudnevsky
Тогда я, в рамках ликвидации безграмотности, буду ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО следить за Вашими ответами, и, если придумаю решение эффективнее, чем Ваше, то обязательно поставлю Вам -1. Договорились?

Comment: @_vb_   Перестаньте флудить уже. Делать массовое сложение через += для строк - пошло и позорно если уж на то пошло.

Comment: да пожалуйста, если Вам заняться нечем :) мне то что)
и заметьте, я Вам минусов не ставил, а только замечание сделал :p